# Collection view every next cell should visible 10% in the current screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have many collection view cells. I want to show two collection view cells on the screen with respect to first cell (A) should visible 90% of the screen and second cell (B) should visible 10% in the present screen, if i scroll to next cell. first cell (A) visible 10% of the screen and second cell (B) visible 90% of the screen.

I was Achieved by below code.

1. Perfectly working if i have 2 cells
2. Not exactly working if i have more than 2 cells.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let value = 0.9;
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*CGFloat(value)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

RefImage:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGdNO.png)

Comment: I didnt understand, you want cells A, C, E, G... to be 90% and B, D, H... to be 10%?

Comment: i am expecting current visible cell should be 90% and the next cell should visible 10% on the screen. but if you observe cell 2 it not visible 90% of the cell it shows only 75 %. some part of cell is moving to left.

Comment: I guess you want `isPagingEnabled` to be true here for the expected behavior. Can you explain your use case for 3 cells A, B and C? Page 1 [A-90%, B-10%], Page 2 [A-10%, B-90%] OR [A-5%, B-90%, C-5%], Page-3 [B-10%, C-90%].

Comment: Thanks in advance i was enable isPagination set as true my use case is 3 cells A, B and C? Page 1 [A-90%, B-10%], Page 2 [A-5%, B-90%, C-5%], Page-3 [B-10%, C-90%].